# How to stop Edge Chromium from showing 'Restore Pages' Pop Up

Tags: popup, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

How to stop Edge Chromium version 94.0 from showing 'Restore Pages' Pop Up

Answer (score 1):

Since Edge 100, there a new registry key to control this :

HideRestoreDialogEnabled = 1 (DWORD)
in
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

So now, when you shutdown Windows 10-11 without previously closing Edge, you won't get prompted to restore pages upon reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In "Edge browser", click reset to standardsettings and try Enable "startupboost" in "Edge browser" version "96.0.1054.43".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Is the Edge browser got crashed or gets closed due to any reason?

If yes, then it is expected behavior to get the 'Restore Pages' popup. You could click the suitable option from the popup.

If you are closing the Edge browser normally without any problem and facing the said issue then there are several things you could try that might help you fix the said issue.

1. Open tabs from the previous session.

- Launch the Edge browser.
- Paste `edge://settings/startHomeNTP` in the address bar and press the Enter key.
- Select option **Open tabs from the previous session**.

[image]

2. Turn off 'startup boost'.

- Launch the Edge browser.
- Paste `edge://settings/system` in the address bar and press the Enter key.
- Turn off 'startup boost' option.

[image]

3. If there is a new update available for the Edge browser then install the latest updates and see if it fixes the issue.
4. Modify the **RestoreOnStartup** registry key.

- Launch the Registry Editor.
- Browse to location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`.
- Set the value of **RestoreOnStartup** to 0. (If the key and value are not there then you could add it manually.)

[image]

After testing the above suggestions, if you still facing the said issue then you could press the `ALT + SHIFT + I` key in the Edge browser window and provide the feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried that but to no avail. I have reached out to Microsoft

Comment: I can't find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge` win11-x64.